# Set image and page number in header using mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I have used mpdf library. Everything is fine but **how can I add image in header** with page number? Page number is displaying but I also have to display image in header.
How to set image in `$mpdf->setHeader()` function?
Any one can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader(' {PAGENO} / {nb}');

mpdf version 6.0
Note: everything should be in single quote.